# Using external CSS library in Kotlin/JS

Tags: css, font-awesome, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I am not a frontend developer and not familiar with npm, yarn and this sort of tools.
However I want to render some data in a Kotlin/JS project.
Particularly, I want to use `font-awesome` icons in my page.
I've added `implementation(npm("font-awesome", "4.7.0"))` to the gradle file and import it in my `index.html` as following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <title>JS Client</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="library.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run my project and open it in the browser, html and js files are fetched from server except `font-awesome.css` which is getting 404 error.

What is the correct way to use `font-awesome` or other libraries in my project?

BTW, I've also added `js("require('font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css')")` to my `Main.kt`. But there is no change whether I comment it out or not. In both cases, the project is compiled and page is loaded without any problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Alongside `index.html` mentioned above, I have also `gradle.build.kts` and `Main.kt` in my project those are:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.8.20"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.8.20"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/kotlinx-html/maven")
}

kotlin {
    js(IR) {
        binaries.executable()
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport {
                    enabled.set(true)
                }
            }
        }
        binaries.executable()
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")

            }

        }
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(npm("font-awesome", "4.7.0"))


                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html:0.8.0")
                compileOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-browser-js:1.0.0-pre.549")
                runtimeOnly("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
package com.example

import kotlinx.browser.window

fun main() {
    window.onload = {
        js("require('font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css')")
    }
}
```

To run the project, I run `gradle jsBrowserRun`.

**NOTE:**

There exists `build/js/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css`.

Comment: could you create a minimal reproduction of this?

Comment: I just edited the post and explained all files.

Comment: To run it, just execute `gradle jsBrowserRun`.

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts looks like you've misspelt `font-awesome.css` (replace with `fontawesome.css`, or alternatively use `all.css` for debug temporarily). Also, could you show us your file tree, specifically where `index.html` is?

Comment: Nothing is changed with `fontawesome.css` and `all.css`. Also note that `index.html` is generated by IDEA when I created the new Kotlin multi-platform project and located in `library/src/jsMain/resources/`.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
/* 
 * Should be as same as "import "@font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
 * in a normal webpack project
 */
@JsModule("font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css") // I'm not sure if the path is correct
@JsNonModule
external val Style: dynamic

fun main() {
   // This line is required
   Style
}
```